# How to get user ID, username from PHP and MySQL while user is logged in

Tags: php, mysql

I have this issue where I can't get user ID and username from database and store it into variable while user is logged in.(Only works with e-mail.) This is my code.

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $password = md5($_POST['password']);
      if (empty($email) or empty($password)) {
        $error = 'All fields are requred!';
      }
      else {
        $query=$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? AND password = ? ');
        $query->bindValue(1, $email);
        $query->bindValue(2, $password);
        $_SESSION['email']=$email;
        $query->execute();
        $num=$query->rowCount();
        if ($num == 1) {
          $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
          header('Location: index.php');
          exit();
        }
        else {
          $error = 'Incorrect data';
        }
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "while a user is logged in" - if a user has an active session and navigates to a .php page you simply execute the code? or do you mean at the time of logging in?

Comment: your code seems to have a `}` too many

Comment: I use this code to login into web page and I need to get ID of this user from MySQL and store it into some $_SESSION variable but it only works with $_SESSION['email'] variable.

Comment: There is another if statement before so it might look like there is too many }.

Comment: @RichardGaál Please [edit] your question to include the table definition of the `user` table as a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @RichardGaál You shouldn't use `SELECT *`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Comment: @RichardGaál Do not use your own password hashing system, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the "execute" method of prepared statement but nowhere you are calling the "fetch" method. So in your code when you get rowcount as 1, you are setting a session variable indicating successful login. There you need to add following code:

```
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now the the variable $row will have all your fields and only then you can add values to session variables like user id. So assuming your user table has "user_id" as the field, you can add code like this:

```
if ($num == 1) {
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete bindValue rows and try to execute like this

```
$query=$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? AND password = ? ');
$query->execute([$email, $password]);
```

Look at examples here https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php